# Word splitting in MS Word xml source

Tags: microsoft-word, xml

There is an apllication wich use the Word documents as templates. The program use the xml of a Word document as a string an it searches certain strings in it with the help of the indexOf function. My problem is Word splits words two or multiple parts due to change tracking. For example:

```
> %PARTADAT</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR="00084EA4"><w:rPr><w:sz   
> w:val="21" /><w:szCs w:val="21" /></w:rPr><w:t>_RS%
```

Here the %PARTADAT_RS% word would be acceptable for indexOf function.

Can anybody help me how I can turn off this function in the MS Word or ... I do not know, please. Unfortunately I do not any idea.

**UPDATE**
After I edited the Word 'template' I copied its whole text and pasted into a new one. As I noticed the change tracking marks disappeared.

Comment: [Turn off track changes - Word](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/turn-off-track-changes-85a31f26-d593-42eb-9fe1-2fdf081d18f6)

Comment: OK, but it did not work for me or I was just clumsy but thank you for your answer.